# Multiple comparisons inside for loops don't break php code. Why?

Tags: php, for-loop

Why this piece of code works when it is clearly wrong in the second for loop (`for ($i==0; $i<$parts; $i++) {`)?
Does php allows for multiple comparisons inside `for` loops?

```
function split_integer ($num,$parts) {
    $value = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $result = [];
    $modulus = $num%$parts;

    if ($modulus == 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $parts; $i++)
        {
            $value = $num/$parts;
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $valueMod = $parts - ($num % $parts);
        $value = $num/$parts;

        for ($i==0; $i<$parts; $i++) {
            if ($i >= $valueMod) {
                $result[] = floor($value+1);
            } else {
                $result[] = floor($value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: why is it wrong?

Comment: `$i==0` is a typo.

Comment: @u_mulder yeah but it works. Why?

Comment: Because the first expression in the `for` syntax only serves the purpose to initialize your loop variables. `$i == 0` doesn’t do that, of course - but you had set `$i = 0;` at the beginning of your function already, so all that’s necessary to perform this loop is in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code `for ($i==0; $i < $parts; $i++)` **runs** because `$i==0` has no impact on loop.

In normal `for` loop first statement just **sets** `$i` or any other counter's **initial value**. As you already set `$i` to 0 earlier, your loop runs from `$i = 0` until second statement `$i < $parts` is not true.

Going further, you can even **omit** first statement:

```
$i = 0;
for (; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

And loop will still run **3 times** from `0` to `2`.

Comment: Might make sense to mention, that _all three_ expressions can be omitted - `for(;;)` is a valid loop. (Granted, one that runs infinitely, and therefor probably not something for everyday use. But it could still be left at some point via a `break` inside, based on some condition.) OP seems to lack a general understanding of how `for` loops work, I think.